# Java rounding to nearest 0.05

Tags: java, math, rounding

I am trying to find a way to round values to the nearest 0.05.  For example:

- 0.93 rounds to 0.95
- 0.81 rounds to 0.80
- 0.65 stays 0.65
- 0.68 to 0.70
- 0.67 to 0.65

Is there a simple way to do this in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: yes, possible. Did you try anything? Is it a homework?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One option for doing this would be as follows:

1. Multiply the value by 20.
2. Use `Math.round` to round to the nearest integer.
3. Divide by 20 again.

For example:

```
double rounded = Math.round(x * 20.0) / 20.0;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again for you answer, I was wandering is it possible to make rounding like this: 0.95 rounds to 1, 0.94 rounds to 0.90, 0.89 rounds to 0.85

Comment: why 20? There no explaination?

Comment: @EyoeID 20 = 1 / 0.05.