# Python round a float to nearest 0.05 or to multiple of another float

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, rounding-error

I want to emulate [this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.floor%28v=office.15%29.aspx). I want to round a floating point number down to the nearest multiple of 0.05 (or generally to the nearest multiple of anything).

I want this:

```
>>> round_nearest(1.29, 0.05)
1.25

>>> round_nearest(1.30, 0.05)
1.30
```

I can do this:

```
import math

def round_nearest(n, r):
    return n - math.fmod(n, r)

>>> round_nearest(1.27, 0.05)
1.25  # Correct!

>>> round_nearest(1.30, 0.05)
1.25  # Incorrect! Correct would be 1.30.
```

The incorrect answer above is presumably due to floating point rounding. I could put some special case check to see if the `n` is "close enough" to a multiple of `r` and not do the subtraction, and that would probably work, but is there a better way? Or is [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256018/223486) the best option?

Comment: Try this out :)
return (n+(r-(n%r)))

Comment: What do you want `my_magical_rounding(1.29, 0.05)` to give? `1.30` or `1.25`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can round down to the nearest multiple of `a` like this:

```
def round_down(x, a):
    return math.floor(x / a) * a
```

You can round to the nearest multiple of `a` like this:

```
def round_nearest(x, a):
    return round(x / a) * a
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.  In Python 3.9.5, `round_down(4.6, 0.2)` returns `4.4` whereas I would expect it to return `4.6`.

Comment: @nimble_ninja Consider my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70210770/). It returns 4.6 for `round_down(4.6, 0.2)` as is expected.

Answer (score 25):

As [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425782/) wrote:

> You can round to the nearest multiple of a like this:
>
> ```
> def round_nearest(x, a):
>     return round(x / a) * a
> ```

Works nearly perfectly, but `round_nearest(1.39, 0.05)` gives 1.4000000000000001.
To avoid it I'll recommend to do:

```
import math

def round_nearest2(x, a):
    return round(round(x / a) * a, -int(math.floor(math.log10(a))))
```

Which rounds to precision `a`, and then to number of significant digits, that has your precision `a`

**EDIT**

As @Asclepius shown this code has limitation to the first digit in precision (meaning that e.g. if you put 4.3 then rounding is done to closest integer, if you put 0.25 then number is rounded to first decimal digit after all. This can be easily fix by finding how many digits actually precision contains, and rounding to this number after all:

```
def round_nearest(x, a):
    max_frac_digits = 100
    for i in range(max_frac_digits):
        if round(a, -int(math.floor(math.log10(a))) + i) == a:
            frac_digits = -int(math.floor(math.log10(a))) + i
            break
    return round(round(x / a) * a, frac_digits)
```

`frac_digits` is rounded log10 of your precision (nearest number), so it basically shows how many fractional digits should be taken into account (or in case of bigger number - integer digits). So if your precision is 0.25 then `frac_digits` will be equal to 2, because of 2 fractional digits. If your precision is 40 then `frac_digits` will be equal to -1, because you need to 'go back' one digit from decimal separator.

Comment: Reusing the configuration of `a` doesn't seem wise. For example, `round_nearest2(82.0, 4.3)` should return 81.7 but it returns 82.0.

Comment: @Asclepius this was code limitation to first digit of precision, I haven't thought about multidigit precision. You can check updated answer, now also supports multiple digit precision.

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425782/) fails the test `round_down(4.6, 0.2) == 4.6`.

This answer has two types of solutions, *inexact* and *exact*. They pass all previous tests and more, also with negative numbers. Each approach provides solutions for `round_nearest`, `round_down`, and `round_up`.

As a disclaimer, these solutions require a lot more testing. Where [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) is used, its default tolerances apply.

Can you find a failing example?

To devise additional exact solutions, consider [this reference](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/).

##### Using [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) (inexact)

```
import math

def round_nearest(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    return round(num / to) * to  # Credited to Paul H.

def round_down(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    nearest = round_nearest(num, to)
    if math.isclose(num, nearest): return num
    return nearest if nearest < num else nearest - to

def round_up(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    nearest = round_nearest(num, to)
    if math.isclose(num, nearest): return num
    return nearest if nearest > num else nearest + to

# Tests:
rn, rd, ru = round_nearest, round_down, round_up

> rn(1.27, 0.05), rn(1.29, 0.05), rn(1.30, 0.05), rn(1.39, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001)
> rn(-1.27, 0.05), rn(-1.29, 0.05), rn(-1.30, 0.05), rn(-1.39, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.3, -1.3, -1.4000000000000001)
> rn(4.4, 0.2), rn(4.5, 0.2), rn(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6000000000000005)
> rn(-4.4, 0.2), rn(-4.5, 0.2), rn(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6000000000000005)
> rn(82, 4.3)
81.7

> rd(1.27, 0.05), rd(1.29, 0.05), rd(1.30, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.25, 1.3)
> rd(-1.27, 0.05), rd(-1.29, 0.05), rd(-1.30, 0.05)
(-1.3, -1.3, -1.3)
> rd(4.4, 0.2), rd(4.5, 0.2), rd(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6)
> rd(-4.4, 0.2), rd(-4.5, 0.2), rd(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.6000000000000005, -4.6)

> ru(1.27, 0.05), ru(1.29, 0.05), ru(1.30, 0.05)
(1.3, 1.3, 1.3)
> ru(-1.27, 0.05), ru(-1.29, 0.05), ru(-1.30, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.25, -1.3)
> ru(4.4, 0.2), ru(4.5, 0.2), ru(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.6000000000000005, 4.6)
> ru(-4.4, 0.2), ru(-4.5, 0.2), ru(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6)
```

##### Using [`math.fmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fmod) (inexact)

```
import math

def round_down(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    if num < 0: return -round_up(-num, to)
    mod = math.fmod(num, to)
    return num if math.isclose(mod, to) else num - mod

def round_up(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    if num < 0: return -round_down(-num, to)
    down = round_down(num, to)
    return num if num == down else down + to

def round_nearest(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    down, up = round_down(num, to), round_up(num, to)
    return down if ((num - down) < (up - num)) else up

# Tests:
rd, ru, rn = round_down, round_up, round_nearest

> rd(1.27, 0.05), rd(1.29, 0.05), rd(1.30, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.25, 1.3)
> rd(-1.27, 0.05), rd(-1.29, 0.05), rd(-1.30, 0.05)
(-1.3, -1.3, -1.3)
> rd(4.4, 0.2), rd(4.5, 0.2), rd(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6)
> rd(-4.4, 0.2), rd(-4.5, 0.2), rd(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.6000000000000005, -4.6)

> ru(1.27, 0.05), ru(1.29, 0.05), ru(1.30, 0.05)
(1.3, 1.3, 1.3)
> ru(-1.27, 0.05), ru(-1.29, 0.05), ru(-1.30, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.25, -1.3)
> ru(4.4, 0.2), ru(4.5, 0.2), ru(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.6000000000000005, 4.6)
> ru(-4.4, 0.2), ru(-4.5, 0.2), ru(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6)

> rn(1.27, 0.05), rn(1.29, 0.05), rn(1.30, 0.05), rn(1.39, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001)
> rn(-1.27, 0.05), rn(-1.29, 0.05), rn(-1.30, 0.05), rn(-1.39, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.3, -1.3, -1.4000000000000001)
> rn(4.4, 0.2), rn(4.5, 0.2), rn(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6)
> rn(-4.4, 0.2), rn(-4.5, 0.2), rn(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6)
> rn(82, 4.3)
81.7
```

##### Using [`math.remainder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.remainder) (inexact)

This section implements only `round_nearest`. For `round_down` and `round_up`, use the same exact logic as in the "**Using `round`**" section.

```
def round_nearest(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    return num - math.remainder(num, to)

# Tests:
rn = round_nearest

> rn(1.27, 0.05), rn(1.29, 0.05), rn(1.30, 0.05), rn(1.39, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4000000000000001)
> rn(-1.27, 0.05), rn(-1.29, 0.05), rn(-1.30, 0.05), rn(-1.39, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.3, -1.3, -1.4000000000000001)
> rn(4.4, 0.2), rn(4.5, 0.2), rn(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6000000000000005)
> rn(-4.4, 0.2), rn(-4.5, 0.2), rn(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6000000000000005)
> rn(82, 4.3)
81.7
```

##### Using [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) (exact)

Note that this is an inefficient solution because it uses `str`.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math

def round_nearest(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    num, to = Decimal(str(num)), Decimal(str(to))
    return float(round(num / to) * to)

def round_down(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    num, to = Decimal(str(num)), Decimal(str(to))
    return float(math.floor(num / to) * to)

def round_up(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    num, to = Decimal(str(num)), Decimal(str(to))
    return float(math.ceil(num / to) * to)

# Tests:
rn, rd, ru = round_nearest, round_down, round_up

> rn(1.27, 0.05), rn(1.29, 0.05), rn(1.30, 0.05), rn(1.39, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4)
> rn(-1.27, 0.05), rn(-1.29, 0.05), rn(-1.30, 0.05), rn(-1.39, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.3, -1.3, -1.4)
> rn(4.4, 0.2), rn(4.5, 0.2), rn(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6)
> rn(-4.4, 0.2), rn(-4.5, 0.2), rn(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6)
> rn(82, 4.3)
81.7

> rd(1.27, 0.05), rd(1.29, 0.05), rd(1.30, 0.05)
(1.25, 1.25, 1.3)
> rd(-1.27, 0.05), rd(-1.29, 0.05), rd(-1.30, 0.05)
(-1.3, -1.3, -1.3)
> rd(4.4, 0.2), rd(4.5, 0.2), rd(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.4, 4.6)
> rd(-4.4, 0.2), rd(-4.5, 0.2), rd(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.6, -4.6)

> ru(1.27, 0.05), ru(1.29, 0.05), ru(1.30, 0.05)
(1.3, 1.3, 1.3)
> ru(-1.27, 0.05), ru(-1.29, 0.05), ru(-1.30, 0.05)
(-1.25, -1.25, -1.3)
> ru(4.4, 0.2), ru(4.5, 0.2), ru(4.6, 0.2)
(4.4, 4.6, 4.6)
> ru(-4.4, 0.2), ru(-4.5, 0.2), ru(-4.6, 0.2)
(-4.4, -4.4, -4.6)
```

##### Using [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) (exact)

Note that this is an inefficient solution because it uses `str`. Its test results are identical to those in the "**Using `decimal.Decimal`**" section. In my benchmarks, approaches using `Fraction` were much slower than those using `Decimal`.

```
from fractions import Fraction
import math

def round_nearest(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    num, to = Fraction(str(num)), Fraction(str(to))
    return float(round(num / to) * to)

def round_down(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    num, to = Fraction(str(num)), Fraction(str(to))
    return float(math.floor(num / to) * to)

def round_up(num: float, to: float) -> float:
    num, to = Fraction(str(num)), Fraction(str(to))
    return float(math.ceil(num / to) * to)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_nearest(x, a):
  return round(round(x / a) * a, 2)
```

It is a slightly different variation.

Comment: Hardcoding 2 makes this answer unable to generalize beyond 0.05. As a trivial example, for `round_nearest(.124, .005)`, it produces 0.12, whereas the correct answer would be 0.125.